# Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported. Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Tags: python, pandas, google-trends

I am using pytrends library to extract google trends and i am getting the following error:

> Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

```
timeframes = []
datelist = pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq="AS")
date = datelist[0]
while date <= datelist[len(datelist)-1]:
    start_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end_date = (date+4).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    timeframes.append(start_date+' '+end_date)
    date = date+3
```

Comment: Error in which line?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese it would happen in 2nd and 4th line of the while loop's body, if I am not mistaken. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't sum a date and a number like `date+4` because who knows which unit this is, `4h`, `4d`,... ?

---

You may use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), here's an example if you meant `days`

```
from datetime import timedelta

end_date = (date + timedelta(days=4)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# ...
date = date + timedelta(days=3)
```

Answer (score 23):

Since you already use Pandas, why bothering importing other stuff? You can do:

```
import pandas as pd                                            # your code
date = pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq="AS")    # your code

freq = 'D'                                                     # 'H' for hours, etc.
date = date + pd.Timedelta(3, unit=freq)                       # Perform the action
print(date)
```

Output (same as azro's answer):

```
DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-04', '2005-01-04', '2006-01-04', '2007-01-04',
               '2008-01-04', '2009-01-04', '2010-01-04', '2011-01-04',
               '2012-01-04', '2013-01-04', '2014-01-04', '2015-01-04',
               '2016-01-04', '2017-01-04', '2018-01-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Another reason for using this approach is that you can find yourself in a situation where you are adding dynamically stuff to a date, inside a method for example, and you are passing the unit as a parameter.

If you were using `timedelta(days=3)`, you wouldn't be able to change anything else (hours, minutes, etc.) but days!