# Expanding dataset and filling missing dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, google-colaboratory

The raw dataset is below:

**DF**
[image: Image of DF]

When the start and end dates differ, we require daily granularity. Daily granularity ensures each row has the same start and end date.

```
x = np.timedelta64(2069211000000000, 'ns')
days = x.astype('timedelta64[D]')
days / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['datedifference'] = (df['End Date'] - df['Start Date'])
df['datedifference2'] = ((df['datedifference']/days)*23) + 1 

df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['datedifference2'])].reset_index(drop = True)
del df2["datedifference"]
del df2["datedifference2"]
```

The above snippet results in the correct number of rows per campaign, but the start and end dates repeat.

**DF2**
[image: Image of DF2]

This is where I'm stuck. I would like to see results like below:

**DF3**
[image: Image of DF3]

Code tried:

```
date = pd.date_range('2022-03-31', '2022-04-10', freq="AS")   
freq = 'D'                                                   
date = date + pd.Timedelta(3, unit=freq)
```

**Error Received**: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported. Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Same error as in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153546/addition-subtraction-of-integers-and-integer-arrays-with-timestamp-is-no-longer)

The code referenced in the above stack overflow does not work for my dataset, as my data is not linear.

I've tried so many different snippets, with no luck. I've started considering extracting month, day, and year into separate columns, but this would be way more convoluted than I'd like. Open to suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Try with `apply`, `pd.date_range` and `explode`:

```
df["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"])
df["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End Date"])

df["Start Date"] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["Start Date"], row["End Date"]), axis=1)
df["End Date"] = df["Start Date"]
df = df.explode(["Start Date", "End Date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df
      Campaign Start Date   End Date
0   Campaign A 2022-03-31 2022-03-31
1   Campaign A 2022-04-01 2022-04-01
2   Campaign A 2022-04-02 2022-04-02
3   Campaign A 2022-04-03 2022-04-03
4   Campaign B 2022-03-31 2022-03-31
5   Campaign B 2022-04-01 2022-04-01
6   Campaign B 2022-04-02 2022-04-02
7   Campaign C 2022-04-06 2022-04-06
8   Campaign C 2022-04-07 2022-04-07
9   Campaign C 2022-04-08 2022-04-08
10  Campaign C 2022-04-09 2022-04-09
11  Campaign C 2022-04-10 2022-04-10
```